# Not able to open localhost/phpmyadmin with nginx

Tags: php, nginx

Before starting I installed XAMPP. Now am trying to use nginx instead of Apache. For that I did the following steps:

1. Installed nginx (1. c:>cd nginx 1.8.0   2. start nginx). installed successfully.
2. Now am not able to load php files and localhost/phpmyadmin.

Comment: On XAMPPControl Panel : top right corner: check Apache,MySQL,.. to auto start :)

Comment: i dint get where is auto start in XAMPP controll panel...i hav only Apache, MYSQL,...

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of reasons for this behavior. Could you run through some of the following options? If they don't outright solve the issue they should provide greater context to help us resolve this.

1. What happens when you attempt to pull up the "localhost/phpmyadmin" website? If it attempts to save a file then nginx may not be properly configured to interact with the PHP interpreter to process the PHP code and provide it to the web server (nginx).
2. In the directory of your nginx installation there should be a "sites-available" directory containing a plain text "default" file. In this server you should find a declaration of a server block which, in turn, contains an identifier for the document root referred to as "root." Does this point to the directory containing the phpMyAdmin source code?
3. Are you able to pull up just "localhost"?
4. If option 3 is unsuccessful you can run something like "netstat -na | findstr /c:':80'". This will tell you if nginx is actually listening on port 80.
5. If option 3 is unsuccessful but option 4 shows results, you may want to pull up the listening IP address (or your assigned/static IP if it shows 0.0.0.0:80) in your web browser. For example: "192.168.1.100/phpmyadmin"

I hope this triage helps find the underlying cause of your issue.

Comment: Am able to pull up jst localhost(am getting Welcome to nginx!

If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.). but if i try localhost/phpmyadmin am getting (404 Not Found

nginx/1.8.0)

Answer (score -2):

I open the apache with Xampp from the IP direction and it works ok, that is in localhost it not work and in IP direction work fine.